# what if the angular does not have **ngOnInit** and only has **constructor**,what will happen? it still work?

Tags: angular

What if the angular doesn't have  **ngOnInit** and only have **constructor**, what will be happened? it still works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work,

The only thing that you have to be aware is that the OnInit is not implemented on the controller and even you can call it without the implementation.

[OnInit documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

[Lifecycle documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

The life cycle hooks are called regardless if you want to implement them or not.

The are not constrained by your implementation of your component.

Same way if you don't implement a constructor for a class it will but you can still create it as it will use the default.